# Maximum and minimum of sets

Tags: combinatorics

In a city of 1000, 900 people have dogs and 500 people have cats. The minimum number of people with both dogs and cats are A, and the maximum number is B. determine A+B

for the minimum people i calculated it with the venn diagram and got 400,
900+500-x=1000

for the maximum I am not sure but is it 400 too? or 500 considering all the people that have cats have both dogs and cats?

Answer (score 0):

It is $500$. If $500$ have cats and $900$ have dogs, the maximum number of both cats and dogs will be the number in the smallest set, as it can obviously be contained in the larger set. Hope that helped!

Comment: thanks, but doesn't that make the number of people who have dogs become 1000?

Comment: No, imagine the people are numbered from $1$ to $1000$. It could be that people numbered from $1$ to $500$ have both cats and dogs, people numbered $501$ to $900$ have dogs only, and people numbered $901$ to $1000$ have neither.

Comment: got it, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, don't hesitate to ask anything else :)